# Ubuntu touch install SM-G900H where adb reboot bootloader doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have been struggling to get my Samasung Galaxy (SM-G900H) to reboot to bootloader to continue with the install of Ubuntu Touch.

I have tried rooting, using Unified_Android_ToolKit (to get any response from bootloader), reloading lollipop and rooting again ... and still the same result. Phone merrily reboots into android even when using adb command from Ubuntu desktop or even hen using reboot into booloader from Recovery.

Am a bit stumped - is there any way to get Ubuntu onto my phone (conventional or unconventional) ?  I'm not even sure if it is ported to my device, but really want to get or try it (even if it breaks my phone).